# Chart.js Bezier's curves when the numbers are the same

Tags: javascript, angular, chart.js, bezier

I have 4 values 1, 1, 0, 0. for Jun, jul, Aug and sept. When the lines transitions from jun to jul (both have a value of 1) the line curves and curves off canvas, Then the same happens from Aug to Sept as both values are 0.  Is there a way to change this behaviour without going to non bezier lines?

[image: The Curve]

Comment: Well that's what Bezier cubic interpolation does.

Comment: No, it should not go off the canvas, can you post the code, please. Also look at this fiddle I have plotted using the same dataset https://jsfiddle.net/e8n4xd4z/20567/

Comment: If those are control points then it should not go off the canvas, the curve will always stay within the convex hull. But as @pointy "pointed" out if the points are used as interpolation points then the curve is correct.

Comment: @GarCB613 Bezier splines do not interpolate their control points; it could be that Chart.js uses Catmull-Ramm cubic splines, which do. In any case, the whole point of spline interpolation is to ensure smooth (differentiable) curves.

Comment: Do you have a [mcve] to show what you're actually doing; maybe your problem is inherent to chart.js, maybe you forgot some obvious "pick the right interpolation" line, but there is no way for anyone to answer "how do I change this code" if there is no code =)